# Force Closing Thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, download

In my android application I am using a thread to download some data.

Here is a prototype of currently working code:

```
void startThread()
{
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.setPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while(application_running)
    {
        //download my data... (on slow server response, execution gets stuck here)
    }
}
```

Problem occurs when downloading data form the server is very slow. Although i close the application: **data download thread remains alive**. But i need this thread to close immediately after application close.

Is there any way to force close it? Or any other standard way to download data?

Comment: you can call `thread.interrupt()` in `onPause()` method for stop thread, and for your problem in slow connection post logcat error

Answer (score 0):

Use an AsyncTask that is tied to your Activity (or Fragment) lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Assuming you have a member variable for your AsyncTask called t and it has already been started elsewhere within your Activity or Fragment, you can do the following in onDestroy():

```
    if ((t != null) && !t.isCancelled())
    {
        boolean mayInterruptIfRunning = true;
        t.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        t = null;
    }
```

Using an AsyncTask also has the benefit of allowing you to update your UI safely on the UI thread for progress reporting and once your background task completes by overriding the onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute methods.